# Emacs: move point to last non-whitespace character

Tags: emacs

<kbd>M-m</kbd> (`back-to-indentation`) moves point to the first non-whitespace character on the line. I'd like to do the opposite: move point to the last non-whitespace character on the line. I have been unable to find a "built-in" command for this and I'm not familiar enough with ELisp to write something, so any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(defun my-move-end-of-line-before-whitespace ()
  "Move to the last non-whitespace character in the current line."
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line nil)
  (re-search-backward "^\\|[^[:space:]]"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I added `(forward-char)` at the end so that I can just use `C-k` to delete the whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

Normally in this situation I want to get to the last non-whitespace character and also remove the trailing space, so I use this:

```
M-\ runs the command delete-horizontal-space, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.
```

In the rare case that I would want to preserve the whitespace I just use <kbd>M-b</kbd> <kbd>M-f</kbd> (`backward-word`, `forward-word`) which is typically close enough.

Comment: This is useful, but requires that point has already been moved to the correct position.

Comment: Good point. If not already at the end of the line you need to add a `C-e` beforehand.

Comment: Yes, so `C-e` `M-\\` is an alternative solution which moves point to the end of the line and then deletes the extra whitespace. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think already phils answered to your question. Just another POW.. trailing white spaces are very annoying, invisible and prone to bugs(?). So I have a hook for `before-save-hook` to delete them.

```
;;; delete nasty hidden white spaces at the end of lines
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

So it your indented operation becomes simply `C-e` for me.

Comment: Which you can write more simply as `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)`, BTW.

Comment: @sanityinc yes. you are right. deleted the redundant lambda. Thanks

Comment: I recommend the excellent `ws-trim-mode` (also includes `global-` variant) for trimming trailing whitespace. It's quite customisable, but the default configuration will only modify lines which you edit, making it version-control safe (i.e. will not introduce masses of irrelevant changes if you edit a file which had lots of trailing whitespace). ftp://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/emacs/ws-trim.el

Comment: @phils good to know about that. I think it would be very useful when editing others' files. Thanks for informing

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function to bind to C-e (usually `move-end-of-line`). C-e works as usual, but if your pointer is already at the end of the line, it will remove trailing whitespace.

```lisp
(defun my/smarter-move-end-of-line (arg)
  "Move to the last non-whitespace character in the current line.

Move point to end of this line. If point is already there, delete
trailing whitespace from line, effectively moving pointer to last
non-whitespace character while also removing trailing whitespace.

If ARG is not nil or 1, move forward ARG - 1 lines first."
  (interactive "^p")
  (setq arg (or arg 1))

  ;; Move lines first
  (when (/= arg 1)
    (let ((line-move-visual nil))
      (forward-line (1- arg))))
  (let ((orig-point (point)))
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (when (= orig-point (point))
      (delete-horizontal-space))))
```

Remap C-e:

```lisp
;; remap C-e to 'smarter-move-end-of-line'
(global-set-key [remap move-end-of-line]
        'my/smarter-move-end-of-line)
```

Answer (score 0):

My version: Move to end of line or last non-space (by deleting ending spaces)

```
(defun smart-end-of-line ()
  "Move to end of line or last non-space (by deleting ending spaces)"
  (interactive "^")
  (let ((p (point)))
    (end-of-visual-line)
    (if (= p (point)) (end-of-line))
    (if (= p (point)) (let (deactivate-mark) (delete-horizontal-space)))))
(global-set-key [end] 'smart-end-of-line)
(global-set-key "\C-e" 'smart-end-of-line)
```

The `[end]` and `"\C-e"` (control+e) keys:

- Move the cursor (point) the the end of the visual line.
- If it is already at the end of the visual line, then move it to end of the line.
- If it is already there, then move it to last non-whitespace character of the line by deleting all those ending whitespaces.
- While moving, keep the region (`interactive "^"`).
- The `let (deactivate-mark)` is to make sure the region is kept.

This is taken from @justinokamoto; then I add the visual line end. (Sorry for my broken English).